# Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f10001e (Android studio, Jetpack compose)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, resourcesnotfoundexception

When I create a new module in Android Studio, create a siple composable function and try to run a preview on Emulator - get Error...And in the neighboring module I am able to run preview of another function...And it is possible with app as well...Would be grateful for explanation - what the magic is going on? :)

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: <namespace>.signuppersonaldata.test, PID: 9135
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f10001e
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f10001e
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:537)
                                                                                                        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:645)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:216)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

> Clarification - what is going on, what is the reason of this
> exception... Explanation - what tot do to fix it

!NB Update
Philio, you was right - I had dependency from feature module to app module...Deleted it and issue was resolved...Thank you and everyone, who tried to help!

Comment: Have you googled the given error message `Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider`? Please update your question with why none of the solutions that come up with that search won't solve your problem.

Comment: Are your module dependencies correct? If the referenced string is in another module you might need to add it as a dependency.

Comment: If you want people to take time to answer your question, please take time to format it for readability (use paragraphs and code blocks, specifically): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask